# Does fringe pattern depends on width of the slits and whats the pattern look like in case of many slits?

Tags: optics, waves, double-slit-experiment

Consider a general case where we have many slits and we are interested in the pattern effect changed on screen kept at large distance when one of these happens :1. Slit widths of all are changed a bit. And what will be the pattern naturally observed though will it be more like double slit or more like single slit experiment ?

Answer (score 1):

A double (or multiple) slit interference pattern is modulated by a single slit diffraction pattern.  The first minimum in the diffraction pattern occurs when the beam from the center of the slit is out of phase with the beam from the edge of the slit. This cancellation continues as you move across the slit. As the slit gets narrower, this minimum moves to a larger angle.   As the number of slits increases, each maximum in the interference pattern (for each color) becomes narrower and each minimum gets wider. Again as the slit separation decreases, the angle to each maximum increases.

Comment: Is there some formula too which relates the fringe pattern with the slith widths ?

Comment: Also Sir you said its" modulated by single slit diffraction" but that only happens when lambda comparable to wavelength isnt ? We might have lamda>>,<< wavelength too right?

Comment: A single slit minimum occurs when: mλ = a sin(θ) where (a) is the slit width. Yes, (λ) should be comparable to (a).

Comment: Sir what happens in cases of where λ << a , λ >>a ? you spoke of the explanation in that comparable range only , you may expand it to cover all cases :)

Comment: Sir pls tell ??